# Suggest some important ANN's topics for research

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network

What are the best topics for research in Artificial Neural Network(ANN) in your view among vast possible topics?

I just want to know your vision and knowing about the subjects that are up to date and important. For example in my vision finding a better way for choosing the number of Layers and Neurons in each layer at the first(initial) time in ANN is very important.

What you think?

Comment: I think the greatest advances are likely to be made in creating neural networks to automagically identify posts that are unsuited to certain forums :-)

Comment: Is stack overflow really the best place for this kind of suggestion? How do I make a response you can "tick off" as the correct one?

Anyway, there are just too many interesting ANN-topics, but as a big fan of evolution I am interested in techniques for evolving advantageous topologies for ANNs and just E-ANNs in general

Comment: @paxdiablo, also unsuited comments :-)

Comment: The identification of "important" topics is highly opinion-based which makes this kind of off-topic. If you're asking for "challenges" though, the biggest one across all models is finding something better than SGD for training.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion **some** of the most interesting topics are:

- Closing the *gap between neuroscience and artificial intelligence (in computer science)*. We know little to nothing about, e.g., the functionality of biological neural networks like the human brain and how those architectures solve complex tasks and really "create" the thing we commonly know as intelligence. Investigating both, neuroscience and artificial intelligence for co-adapting recent advances could highly boost our understanding of the human brain as well as our ability to really create an intelligent AI.
- *BigData*: Billions of images, texts, audio files and so on are available on the internet but information is meaningless if it can not be made easily accessible for humans. One of the biggest challenges of the 21th century is to develop knowledge technologies for utilizing the abilities that approach with big data.
- *Robotics*: Being able to create more intelligent robots can help humanity to fight starvation and poverty, because robots could potentially be much more productive/efficient in basic tasks like street building, farming, transporting goods, etc. If you free humanity from monotonous jobs you create the potential for more people going into education, science, arts, philosophy and so on. Although this is a highly controversial discussion, I think the potential of this can not be denied.

Comment: Your suggestions are good. Especially I'm interested in number one and two. BigData is one of the most important topics in today's technology day. Thank you.